# Visual Novel Development - Should I be loading all voice and image assets at once?

Tags: c++, assets, sfml, game-development

Should I load all my voice and image assets before I start playing the narrative in my Visual Novel engine?

I'm developing a Visual Novel engine using C++ and SFML, and right now we are loading all the assets from disk as we need them. While it worked fine for prototyping purposes, I noticed that there are lags when I load the voice files, presumably because how long it takes to read from disk.

This motivated me to write a ResourceManager class, which will help load the assets on a separate thread and manage all the loaded assets across the entire program.

I could have developed some algorithm to predict what assets will be needed soon. However, since it is a visual novel with various choices and jumps in the script, these predictions can never be perfect (I don't really know what assets the script writer will include in the script beforehand, so the only way to find out is to parse the script manually). This means that I might still encounter some lags if I decide not to load all the assets at once.

My question right now is, should I use it to load all the voice/image assets at once before entering the main game state, or should I allow the occasional lagging by loading the assets batch-by-batch during the game? Wouldn't the former way take too much memory space?

```
/*ResourceManager.h*/
    #define RESOURCE ResourceManager::m_rscManagerPtr
    ...

/*MainState.h*/
    void init()
    {
      // add the resource and start loading them
      RESOURCE->addFont("font.tff");
      RESOURCE->addTexture("screen.png");
      RESOURCE->addAudio("sound.wav");
      ...
      // change to loading state
      changeState(STATE_LOADING);
    }

/*LoadingState.h*/
    void init()
    {
      // Start loading all the assets added previously
      RESOURCE->startLoading();
    }

    void update()
    {
      // wait till the other thread has done loading assets
      if (!RESOURCE->doneLoading()) { // do something }

      // done loading, return to previous state, which is MainState here
      else changeState(STATE_PREVIOUS);
    }

/*MainState.h*/ 
    void update()
    {
      // get and use the loaded resources
      sf::Font* font = RESOURCE->getFont("font.tff");
      sf::Texture* texture = RESOURCE->getTexture("screen.png");
      sf::Audio* audio = RESOURCE->getAudio("sound.wav");
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Encode all the audio and picture files, so that they cannot be modified by players. Load all the audio and pictures, after decoding ,before the game.

Comment: Yes I do plan to either zip up all the assets and encrypt it with a password, or to encode them manually, but the ResourceManager will probably serve as an interface so that the devs don't need to know whether they are dealing with a zip file or the OS file system.

Comment: Highly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276659/3195314

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where should I store textures for a game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53240918/where-should-i-store-textures-for-a-game)

Answer (score 0):

While loading everything at the start won't be too bad if your game is small, but as it gets bigger you initial loading times would get longer and keeping everything in ram will cause your ram usage to go up too.

You mention your resource manager loads the files on a different thread, so with that you could load the next 3-4 lines of audio or pictures then when the user listens to a line you load the next one, when it comes to branches you load the first few of each branch then discard the one the user does not pick.

Since it's not running on the same thread it shouldn't hitch your game.